# user authentication with existing database

Tags: c#, entity-framework, visual-studio-2013, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

I have an existing database with the table `account` which contains these tables: (int) `USERID`, `EMAIL` and `PASSWORD`. There are more columns, but they are not important for this question. Passwords are hashed with `BCrypt`. The `class Account` in this project also has a `property Role` which will be migrated to the database later.

I have a working ASP.NET project that already works with the accounts and has some functionality. Now I'd like to implement the user login.

I started by editing AccountController. I removed a large part because users cannot register on this site (accounts are created before) and I don't want external login support.

```
[Authorize]
public class AccountController : Controller
{
    private DbSet<Account> accounts; // will become a repo later

    public AccountController()
    {
        this.accounts = new MyContext().Accounts;
    }

    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult Login(string returnUrl)
    {
        ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
        return View();
    }

    //
    // POST: /Account/Login
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
    {

        if (ModelState.IsValid && ValidateLogin(model)) 
        {
            string role = "Student"; // will be saved in Account and DB later
            FormsAuthenticationTicket authenticationTicket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(1, model.UserName, DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now.AddMonths(3), model.RememberMe, role, "/");

            HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(authenticationTicket));
            Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
            HttpContext.User = new GenericPrincipal(new GenericIdentity(model.UserName), new string[] {"role"});
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }

        ModelState.AddModelError("", "The username or password is incorrect");
        return View(model);
    }

    private bool ValidateLogin(LoginViewModel model)
    {
        var account = accounts.SingleOrDefault(x=>x.Email == model.UserName);
        return account != null && BCrypt.CheckPassword(model.Password, account.Password);
    }

    //
    // POST: /Account/LogOff
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult LogOff()
    {
       FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }
}
```

This login check works, but it does not seem to save a cookie, nor does the system know the user is logged in.

Also, is that the best way to go? Maybe I'm better off supporting the `Identity` framework of `MVC 5` by implementing `IdentityUser`, but what other interfaces will I need? How do I support my existing roles? Do I need a new `IdentityDBContext` separate from my existing `DataContext` ?

Comment: To leverage OOB authentication you're probably going to need a custom `MembershipProvider` (just write a class and implement it: it's a lot of code to write, although not very complex) which in turn manages/uses your existing user data